# Event handlers removed when resetting input file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that resets the input file:

```
$(this).replaceWith($(this).clone());
```

However, I noticed that if I used the particular input file, its event firing was not handled. So this the code for handling the event when a file input is changed:

```
$('#frontfile').change(function(){
        reader2 = Main.Mod.image_change(this);
        reader2.onload = rearImageIsLoaded;
    });
```

What seems to be the problem?

Your responses will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass true to the [clone method](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to clone the handlers and data associated with it

```
$(this).replaceWith($(this).clone(true, true));
```

Comment: Or `.clone(true, false)` depending on what you are trying to achieve.